# change background color for highchart candlestick plot

Tags: highcharts

I'm using highcharts candlestick chart to show our data.

In our chart we are actually showing N series with the same amount of data points, so we also want to group data points at the same index together. Like in the picture, each series has 6 data points, and we group 2N-th points of each series together by changing background color.

However we didn't find a way to change background color of candlestick chart, or is there any other way in highcharts could somehow show grouping data together?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `plotBands`. Take a look at the example.

API Reference:
https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/xAxis.plotBands

Example:
http://jsfiddle.net/8jrxx1t2/